# In excel, how do I return values beside a searched string

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I am currently trying to lookup a string value in a range and have it return the value from the cell above or below it. I have tried many formulas to no avail.`=INDEX(B2:J49,MATCH($V$1,B2:J49,0)-1,1)` is what I most recently tried and I just receive `#N/A`. I will attach a picture which can hopefully help you understand what I am trying to do. My main goal is to clean up this table with staircase values.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: MATCH is not two dimensional.  MATCH can scan a single column or a single row, and returns an index number of the cell in that range.  Match can provide a row number in B2:B49, or a column number in B2:J2, but once you apply it to a two-dimensional range MATCH loses its cool.  If the value you are looking for is only in one column, say column E, then just change your MATCH 2nd argument to E2:E79 and leave the rest of the function the same.

Comment: The picture was not uploaded successfully, try to upload the picture again.